# apt-mirror local network repository

Tags: package-management, repository, apt-mirror, localrepository

I have a segment of a network, that doenst have access to the internet. But it's full with mashines which are Ubuntu 16.04
Time to time, from this segment of network i have to download some standart packages but i cant, becouse i have no chance to get internet in this zone.
So i used apt-mirror, downloaded whole repos, which was indicated in initial **source.list** file of any ubuntu 16.04. Its about 500GB.
But, when i try to install something more then "mc" or some generic package, i stuck in a dependency hell. For example, trying to install "sssd" i recieve:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install sssd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sssd : Depends: python-sss (= 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.15) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: sssd-ad (= 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.15) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: sssd-common (= 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.15) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: sssd-ipa (= 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.15) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: sssd-krb5 (= 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.15) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: sssd-ldap (= 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.15) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: sssd-proxy (= 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.15) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But how the hell it works, when i install packeges the from same repo, but not downloaded in my local pc, but from internet. It means, that apt-mirror doesnt download the whole repo and something miss.
So, i have 2 questions:

1. How can i download the whole repo, which will simulate the work of repo in the internet?
2. If i cant, how can i add packeges to my own local repo and in some time fix  dependencies?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this manual which helped me much

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto.en.html